# How to set a delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I want to send my UserModel with all user informations from a `ViewController` (ShowUserViewController) to another `ViewController` (`ChatViewController`) with a `delegate` but its not working.

In my `ShowUserViewControllers` `user` are all informations I want to send to the ChatViewController.

`var user: UserModel?`

In my `ChatViewController` I have the following declaration where I want to send my datas:

```
var currentUser: UserModel?
```

Here my protocol:

```
    protocol UserInfoToChatID {
    func observeUserID(user: UserModel)
}
```

Here I prepare the segue and set `delegate` by tapping the button:

```
} else if segue.identifier == "UserInfoToChatVC" {
        let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        chatVC.currentUser = self.user
    }
}

var delegate: UserInfoToChatID?

@IBAction func chatButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    delegate?.observeUserID(user: user!)
}
```

At last I call the `delegate` in my `ChatViewController`:

```
    extension ChatViewController: UserInfoToChatID {

    func observeUserID(user: UserModel) {
        self.currentUser = user
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserInfoToChatVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the delegate?  Can you clarify your question; which bits of code are in which view controller

Comment: i edited my question, it now should be a little bit better to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass data from one ViewController to another, you don't have to use delegates for this. You can just pass this data as sender parameter of `performSegue` method:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserInfoToChatVC", sender: user!)
```

then in prepare for segue just downcast sender as `UserModel` and assign destination's `currentUser` variable

```
    ...
    } else if segue.identifier == "UserInfoToChatVC" {
        let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        chatVC.currentUser = sender as! UserModel
    }
}
```

---

But in your case you actually don't have to pass `user` as sender. You can just assign destination's `currentUser` variable as `ShowUserViewController`'s global variable `user`

```
    ...
    } else if segue.identifier == "UserInfoToChatVC" {
        let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        chatVC.currentUser = user!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2 things: 
first, if you just want to pass data from one viewController to other viewController you don't need to use delegate pattern, just pass the object to the next viewController on prepare form segue.

second, if you want to implement the delegate pattern you should have one viewController than call to the delegate and the other implement the functions.

example:

```
protocol ExampleDelegate: class {
   func delegateFunction() 
}


class A {
   //have delegate var
   weak var delegate: ExampleDelegate?

   // someWhere in the code when needed call to the delegate function... 
   delegate?.delegateFunction()
}

Class B: ExampleDelegate {
   func delegateFunction() {
      // do some code....
   }

   //when you move to the next viewControoler(to A in that case)
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AClass" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? A {
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile `weak var delegate` should be used with class bound protocol. update your answer with `protocol ExampleDelegate` --> `protocol ExampleDelegate:class`

Answer (score 1):

To pass the UserModel object forward, from `ShowUserViewController` to `ChatViewController`, you should use something called `Dependency Injection`:

So you'll do something like this inside `ShowUserViewController`:

```
@IBAction func chatButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "UserInfoToChatVC", sender: nil)
}
```

Note: The sender parameter should be the object that initiated the segue. It could be self, i.e. the `ShowUserViewController` object, but I'd advise against passing the `UserModel` object, because that object did not initiate the segue, and has nothing to do with navigation at all. It should be injected inside the `Destination Controller` later on.

In the same file, override the `prepare(for:)` method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "UserInfoToChatVC" {
        let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        chatVC.currentUser = self.user
    }
}
```

I believe you've mostly done this part right, but you may need to communicate back from `ChatViewController` to `ShowUserViewController`.

In that case, you can and should use `Delegation`.

Create something like this inside `ShowUserViewController`:

```
protocol ChatViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func didUpdateUser(_ model: UserModel)
}

class ChatViewController: UIViewControler {

    var user: UserModel?

    weak var delegate: ChatViewControllerDelegate?
    /* more code */

    func someEventHappened() {
        delegate?.didUpdateUser(self.user!)
    }
}
```

Finally, there is an additional line to be added to the `prepare(for:)` method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "UserInfoToChatVC" {
        let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
        chatVC.currentUser = self.user
        // Add this line...
        chatVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

And specify that the `ShowUserViewController` implements the `ChatViewControllerDelegate` protocol, then override the `didUpdateUser(_:)` method:

```
func didUpdateUser(_ model: UserModel) {
    // Some code here
}
```

Comment: weak var delegate: ChatViewControllerDelegate should be used with class bound protocol --> Update your answer with  protocol ChatViewControllerDelegate:class